# Making a []byte typesafe in golang

Tags: arrays, go, struct, byte

I'm new to GO and want to learn how to read a byte array and make structs based on certain bytes I'm receiving. I'm reading a BMP file, which has file- and info headers that I want to parse into structs. How would I go about doing that?

For example I want to have `bitmapFileHeader` be of the type `BITMAPFILEHEADER`

```
type BITMAPFILEHEADER struct {
    BfType      uint16
    BfSize      uint32
    BfReserved1 uint16
    BfReserved2 uint16
    BfOffBits   uint16
}

func main() {
    var result []byte

    data, _ := os.ReadFile("assets/courtyard.bmp")
    bitmapFileHeader := data[:14] // how do I parse this into BITMAPFILEHEADER
    bitmapInfoHeader := data[14:54]
    bitmap := data[54:]

    result = append(result, bitmapFileHeader...)
    result = append(result, bitmapInfoHeader...)
    result = append(result, bitmap...)

    os.WriteFile("out/result.bmp", result, 0644)
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for encoding/binary ? In any case: Never ignore errors and take the Tour of Go for language fundamentals. If you want to **learn** something: Do the conversion yourself.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. Just wanted to know what the best way to do a conversion is in golang...

Comment: There is no "best" way. There are just different types of trade offs.

Comment: You're ignoring the error result from `os.ReadFile`.  So you don't know whether you're "getting errors' or not.  Look at https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/image/bmp which can help read the bitmap image

Comment: @DanielFarrell yes I know about that library, but I want to actually write it myself :)

Comment: @Volker Well, no thanks to you I'm actually making progress by using `binary.Read()` and can now actually query into my struct. Lesson learned, StackOverflow is apparently not the right place for golang questions :)

Answer (score -1):

As someone on Reddit pointed out I can use [binary.Read()](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Read) to read a byte array into a struct.

```golang
type BITMAPFILEHEADER struct {
    BfType      uint16
    BfSize      uint32
    BfReserved1 uint16
    BfReserved2 uint16
    BfOffBits   uint16
}

func main() {
    data, error := os.ReadFile("assets/courtyard.bmp")

    if error != nil {
        panic(error)
    }

    buffer := bytes.NewReader(data)

    var bitmapFileHeader BITMAPFILEHEADER
    binary.Read(buffer, binary.LittleEndian, &bitmapFileHeader)

    fmt.Println(bitmapFileHeader.BfType)
}
```